# TCP/IP listener Web application .net

Tags: .net, web-services, web-applications, tcp

Referred link-   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/winsock_revamped.aspx

We have developed VB.Net application or windows application, it receives client connection request by TCP/IP listener, Client application developed using VB6 programming language. The windows chat server is been developed based on above link's sample code.

My application is a database for hotels that takes orders from VB6 App. Since we had existing VB6 application that had all the features , database etc. Also the VB6 PC uses TCPIP listener for nodes in the LAN to get data. Now we are planning to change the Nodes to website. The server (VB6 application running on local PC), I do not want to change, just the nodes we want to shift to Web.

Communication between client and server is working fine, there is no problem, but I'm trying to develop a web application. So my question is TCP listener supported on Web application or any equivalent ? , or Is better to using web service for communication in case of Web application?

The web application ASP.net(VB/C# .net 3.5)will be running on dedicated server windows 2003 R2. 
As of now we could create a Windows application and we are trying to install the same on the Web Server. The chat server application that I created for testing worked ok on my LAN, I am not sure whether it will work on Web Server as well. In case of LAN, I used LAN IP, for internet, I will have to use Internet IP. If this works, will it have security concerns or problems. The desired port for TCP/IP communication of this is been kept open on the web server.

framework 3.5, VS2008 for TCP/IP Listener Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

At it's essence your web server is actually just one big TcpListener, highly optimized for concurrent use.  So with that in mind, I don't see the point of opening another TcpListener within a session request just to send chat messages.

The better aproach would be to use web requests and Ajax to do this sort of thing.  I'm certain that there are plenty 'web chat server' example projects out there to demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry, existing application is not chat server, its rather database for hotels. I updated my question to reflect the same.